# What is the earliest notification that I can get that a user has logged on to Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-3.0

I'm writing an application in C# (.net 3.5) and I have a Windows service that runs as System.  I want that service to receive the *earliest, quickest* notification possible as soon as a person logs on to the computer interactively, whether that be physical or through Remote Desktop.  Something event-driven I think would be preferable to rapid polling, though I understand if polling for something is as good as I can get.  I also think I want to especially avoid polling the Security event logs because that is very slow and resource intensive. The lighter weight the better.

Comment: I think the earliest notification you could get would be by changing the Shell registry key, but `WTSRegisterSessionNotificationEx` should get you pretty close.

Comment: Or `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications to your service. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @William OK thank you - I have already tried putting something in the Userinit key, which I think preempts even the shell, but that wasn't quite early enough. I will try your suggestions above.

Comment: Consider installing a network credential manager.  This gets called at a much earlier stage in logon, and is also synchronous, i.e., until the credential manager returns from the notification the logon will not proceed.